# Hiding columns without using a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that uses a For loop to hide a number of columns based on a Cell value.  The code is used in 7 sheets out of a Workbook that has 17 sheets in total (this information is relevant later).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_calculate()
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    On Error GoTo errorHandling
        Dim controlCell As Range, tableToHide As Range
        Set controlCell = Range("C12") 'Cell contains a formula to retrieve the value from a cell in a seperate sheet
        Set tableToHide = Range("Table1") 'The name of the table where columns need to be shown/hidden based on controlCell value

        tableToHide.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        For i = controlCell.Value To tableToHide.Columns.Count
            tableToHide.Columns(i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Next i
    errorHandling:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I'm looking for a way to hide the columns without using a loop or a way to change this loop.  The reason for wanting the change is because when this is used in its current form, changing **any cell** throughout the Workbook's 17 sheets results in a loading spinner showing for a few seconds.  As you can imagine, that is not a great user experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hide all columns at once. Various ways to do so, eg

```
Dim startCol As Long
startCol = controlCell.value
Dim hideRange As Range
Set hideRange = tableToHide.Cells(1, startCol).Resize(1, tableToHide.Columns.Count - startCol + 1)
hideRange.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you have this code inside the `Worksheet_calculate()` event: this causes the entire workbook to be checked every time a calculation is made.

Why don't you put that for-loop inside another macro, which you can run on demand, and use the `Worksheet_calculate()` event only to check the column you're actually calculating?

Comment: I wanted it to be automated and not a clickable event.